aks internal load balancer not working properly
I try to deploy AKS with internal load balancer enabled.
Internal load balancer is deployed by istio ingress gateway.
profile.yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio-controlplane
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
  components:
    egressGateways:
    - name: istio-egressgateway
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
    ingressGateways:
    - name: istio-ingressgateway
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
        serviceAnnotations:
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
        service:
          type: LoadBalancer
          loadBalancerIP: 10.1.2.254
          ports:
            - port: 5000
              targetPort: 5000
              name: store-front
            - port: 5001
              targetPort: 5001
              name: web-service
    pilot:
      k8s:
        env:
          - name: PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING
            value: "100"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 100Mi
  values:
    global:
      proxy:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
    pilot:
      autoscaleEnabled: false
    gateways:
      istio-egressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: false
      istio-ingressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: false

gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 5000
      name: sample
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"
  - port:
      number: 5001
      name: app
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: store-front
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sample
    route:
    - destination:
        host: store-front.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /app
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web-service.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5001

When I tried to connect to http://10.1.2.254/app or http://10.1.2.254/sample from VM via VNet peering, it didn't work.
So I deployed a test pod and tried to curl , it didn't work either.
It seems VirtualService is not working properly.
Is there any cause about it?
kubectl version: v1.30.0
istioctl version: 1.22.3
